# GPS location API?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, api, gps

Is there an api or a way to get the GPS location of a certain address ?

I have to loop through a list and get the GPS longitude and latitude.

Regards,
kimos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding)

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739)

You can use [Google Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you just mean you want the longitude and latitude (which aren't tied to GPS) there are various geocoding options. For example:

- [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [Bing Maps Geocode Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx)
- [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/free-geocoding.html) (also has a data dump)

Online geocoding services tend to be via a JSON or XML API, so you don't really *need* a C#-specific client library.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Jon_Skeet & @Hamad are providing you with valid answers. You could use Bing or Google directly to get the lat long details of an address.

However, when iOS6 appears on the scene officially iOS will no longer use google maps. Which presents a couple of issues. As any data passed back from google according to their T & Cs should be presented on a google map. I assume something similar will be the case over at BING. Although, this might not be something you care about.

But to ensure no such issues arrise in the future use the Geocoding functionality provided by Apple [link here for reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html)

Being pedantic you're not looking to geo encode anything you're actually look to revers-geoencode the address.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i indeed asked to implement iOS app.